# Can we have links to the actual user profile in comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-replies, recent-names

I've a situation here - somebody changed my username *(obviously to something I do not wish to have)* using my computer while I was logged in. When I tried to change it back I got an error message saying that I can't change back my username within a month.

Hence I'd to remove all my personal information from my profile, and I feel like I'm using somebody else's Stack Overflow profile, I don't feel like the Stack Overflow me :/

I admit that it's my mistake, but it happened, and it'll have **forever** impact in my profile about which I can't do anything - since, this username *(which I really do not wish to have*) will be there as part of my profile in **recent names** field forever.

Also, if I continue using Stack Overflow till the next month, there'll be comments all over mentioning my current username, which I really do not want.

So, can we have an actual mentioning system for comments, like Facebook, when typing `@` followed by the characters show suggestions (*which is already implemented*) and the selected username becomes a hyperlink which points to the actual user's profile, which will be updated once the user changes his profile information?

**What happens now?**

- The `@username` comments can be confusing if there are two users in a conversation with same username, since usernames are not unique.
- If somebody deletes their comments *(I've seen such conversations many times)* then the other comments become obsolete.
- If somebody changes their username, even though future readers can possibly figure out that the user has changed his username, it doesn't look good, right?

**What we would get from this new feature**

- We can avoid all of the above.
- We can also remove the recent names field in profile (*which I think wouldn't be necessary anymore if we can have comments which link to the actual user profile*).
- I was onto comments all this time, while posting/updating an answer, if we have to refer somebody else's answer or modify the question as per comments, right now we have to manually copy link to their profile and add a hyperlink. If this feature is implemented, typing `@` in an answer could show possible matches for commenters' an well as owners of other answers.

What do you think? Oh, BTW is there any way I can get rid of this username..? (*I've already filed a ticket in the help section and haven't gotten any response so far…*)

*Update: note that my colleague confessed that he did it for fun, and **he didn't get any such warning messages** saying that it can't be undone in a month, otherwise he wouldn't have done it. :/ If so, that's another feature request: can we have a warning message?*

**UPDATE:** I followed [Wooble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble)'s instruction *(Like I said above, I had to manually link to the profile, would be nice to have it automated)* to copy profile from another Stack Exchange site, and it worked..! [image: thumbs up smiley] So, if it is possible to do this, then what's the point in having a *month* barrier? I don't understand the design!

Comment: I actually quite like your name. I can't see your "Recent Names" so I'm guessing it's a private field anyway. The comments thing kinda sucks, but they're second class citizens, so I can't see this happening.

Comment: I hope if someone changes my username they make it grammatically correct or finish the sentence. You have my pity.

Comment: The 1 month username lock is easy to circumvent; you can just go to your account on any other stackexchange site and copy your profile back to SO and it will restore your username.

Comment: FYI: [Why can I only change my Stack Overflow name once every 30 days?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/why-can-i-only-change-my-stack-overflow-name-once-every-30-days) suggests emailing team@stackoverflow.com (If you've already done this, then I guess just wait for a response.)

Comment: I wish I knew what item belonging to the King of Popup you are, then I could empathize with your embarrassment.

Comment: There's a fourth case that I've seen often:  A deleted profile reverts that user's comments to an un-linked "user12345", but responses to that comment still have user12345's original name

Comment: @Wooble wa... that did it friend..! thanks. So if it the username can be changed by copying it from another stack exchange site, then what's the point of having a month waiting time... @__@

Comment: @TilwinJoy: That's a very good question. :)

Comment: @Wooble Well, now you *know* they're going to patch that, now that you let them know about it.  Haha

Comment: @JeffGohlke well what's the point in hiding something like that..? it's extremely unlikely that he gets into a situation like this...

Comment: @JeffGohlke: it's been known for like 4 years; they're probably not going to get around it fixing it any time soon :)

Comment: @TilwinJoy It was just a joke.  As a user, though, it can be good to protect workarounds and vulnerabilities from administrators.  Sometimes you just really want to circumvent some edict... exactly like you just did.  Haha

Comment: @Wooble, going BACK to a previous username vs changing to a different username are distinctly different.  Your suggestion only goes back.

Comment: @paqogomez this is not my previous username in `StackOverflow`… It's a different one (*My StackExchange username was different*).

Comment: Worry not, there are many people who have intentionally ridiculous usernames and it's commonly understood that they're not retards for that reason. So if I see a nice user with a stupid username I'll just assume it was a joke - it's no reason to be embarassed if somebody saw it.

Comment: *since, this username (which I really do not wish to have) will be there as part of my profile in recent names field forever.* No it will not; the recent names list is limited to 90 days.

Comment: If you really want to change your username within a month, you can create an account on a site where you don't have one, change your username there and then save the changes for all sites, and then if you don't want an account on that site you can delete it. I did that with my test sock puppet once to test a bug with long usernames. (I know it's a bit late, but it might help if the same thing happens to someone else.)