# Name of deleted user still visible on self-deleted post

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-users

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327211/multiple-accounts) was asked and deleted by a now-deleted user.

His usercard shows the usual "user6513320" but the banner with the "deleted by" message still contains the real username:

[image: post screenshot]

Shouldn't the name in the banner be 'censored' too?

Comment: On a *deleted* post??  Small fry compared to the [still visible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37550255/17034) @ comments.

Comment: @HansPassant true that, maybe that should also be fixed

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this could also happen with banners on non-deleted posts, such as "protected by" or "closed by"..

Comment: related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-in-close-delete-noti

Comment: As the post notice is just a text field, similar to comments as pointed out by Hans, this is left untouched when a username changes (be it by the user or due to deletion). I expect this to be status-bydesign.

Comment: @HansPassant an old [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261000/2333214) regarding the usernames in comments

Answer (score 13):

This [isn't new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199690/deleted-by-uss). It also manifests in several other places.

As Floern said, this also happens on close banners. Unlike deleted questions, *anyone* can see the names. This was already asked: [Further anonymize deleted accounts by changing the username in close/delete notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901)

Not to mention that you are able to see the name in `@replies`. Information like that, combined with SEDE lets anyone find the information easily.

I did just that to find a question that exhibits this behavior ("Cupcake" was fairly active on meta, which is how I knew the name). Coincidentally, there's another deleted user on this one:

[image: Cupcake is dead]

This also happens with [Area 51 proposals.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/)

---

The bottom line is that they chose their public display name when they signed up, and this shouldn't be something too devastating.

Comment: Man, this post reminds me of how much I miss those two folks, Cupcake and bjb568. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray Have I been summoned?

Comment: @bjb568 I'm confused now. Why isn't your name a link?

Comment: @bjb568 Oh, I didn't realize you were just in stealth mode!

Comment: I guess I'm just a mysterious kat.

Comment: Cupcake account got deleted? Why? .~.

Comment: @CodyGray: Oddly, bjb568's name is still linked in the close review that you can find in the [timeline](//stackoverflow.com/posts/4180682/timeline). Inconsistency much?

Comment: @NathanTuggy If you want inconsistency how about the fact that Cupcake's name *did* get changed to Community in the custom close reason user list below the main user list. ;P

Comment: @animuson Plus bjb568's username appears in two different (frozen) forms.